# ASUS laptop brightness hotkeys stopped working after installing TeamViewer monitor driver

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

We had a problem with a new ASUS PU301LA unit running Windows 7; all the hotkeys were working except the ones for brightness.

We tried reinstalling the ATK (hotkey) driver package from ASUS's website, but it didn't fix the issue. This led us to believe that it might be a problem with the monitor driver. My boss booted up a fresh machine and noticed that the driver used for the laptop display was different from the one on the machine with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the machine and realised it was using the TeamViewer monitor driver. You are given the option to install this driver when you choose to show a black screen and disable remote input on the remote PC you are connecting to.

I uninstalled this driver and manually selected the Generic PnP Monitor driver for the display in Device Manager; then the brightness hotkeys started working again.

The driver did not cause this issue on any of my older machines, including some Dell Latitudes and a few different ThinkPad models.